# Datatable save manually inputted values

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a datatable. It has 2 columns. the first column displays loaded values fom db. and 2nd column has a text box to save manually inputted data.

```
{ //Document type  //4
    "mDataProp": null,
    render: function(data, type, row) {
        return "<input type='textbox' id='reconAmount" + reconJrnlId + "' value='" + data.amount + "' class='form-control'  readonly/>";
    }
},

{//remarks //7
    "mDataProp": null,
    "defaultContent": "",
    render: function (data, type, row, i) {
        var reconJrnlId = (data.jrnlItemId).toString();
        return "<input type='textbox' name='remarks' id='reconRemarks" + reconJrnlId + "' value=' ' class='form-control'/>";
    }
}
```

There is a third column with check box. When check box is clicked,the codes adds in a class to it:

```
row.addClass('selectedrecon');
```

When i do click as save button to retrieve selected records,below, all selected rows are retrieved. But the remarks columns, with manually data is blank! I cant get the manually entered remarks data saved in selected row. Why is it?

```
$.map(table.rows('.selectedrecon').data(), function (item) {
    console.log('----------------->',item);
}
```

Comment: please create a working example of your current code, so that we can understand it properly. You can use stack overflow code editor itself or you can use jsFiddle for that

Comment: Do see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/14nojqLx/6/  . select a check box, add in some data into the text box, and click recon save. do see the console, log, inputted text data is not shown

Comment: May be this helps you:- https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32291/get-the-value-of-input-text-within-table-cell